# Liquibase rollback altered column size to older version

Tags: database, oracle, liquibase

I have 2 changelog versions : 1.0.0 and 1.1.0

In 1.0.0 a field called, let's call it "x_amount" of type VARCHAR2 ( only for the explanation purpose ) with a size of 30
In version 1.1.0 I want to modify the size of "x_amount" to 33.

In case I need to rollback to the version 1.0.0 how can I write the changeset for the rollback so in the case the data added in 1.1.0 version is of 33 chars without losing any data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but you just have to be aware that the rollback will not work in all cases.

Before getting into the details, consider this thought experiment:

- You update from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0, widening the column from 30 to 33.
- lots of data is added, but none is longer than 30 characters
- it is possible to roll back the change if the database itself will allow you - you didn't specify what database type you are using, so whether the database itself will allow it is unclear. [According to this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27223/what-happens-when-you-modify-reduce-a-columns-length), Oracle will allow it if none of the data would be lost.
- Someone uses the database and inserts data into the widened column that is longer than 30.
- It is now impossible to roll back that change without losing data.

So if you are using Oracle, you can just have the changeset look like this:

```
<changSet id="widen-foo-column" author="victor">
  <modifyDataType tableName="some_table" columnName="foo"
        newDataType="VARCHAR2(33)"/>
  <rollback>
    <modifyDataType tableName="some_table" columnName="foo"
          newDataType="VARCHAR2(30)"/>
  </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: I've tried it in a H2 persistent database and the rollback doesn't work i.e. the length of the VARCHAR remained the same.